# What is the difference between these tableware flatware and cutlery?

Tags: fish, butter, knives, utensils

1) May i know specifically in words what the difference(s) are, if any, between 
**a fish knife 
a master butter knife (butter serving knife) and
a fruit knife?**

I have googled sufficiently and found plenty of images of the first two but kind of found no clearly differentiating issues betwen the two

2) Also I'd like to know more about the clasical fruit knife

3) While we are at it what is a salad knife and  afruit fork that pair with salad fork and fruit knife respectively?

4) Finally, how does one use fish server knife and fork pair (which i assume looks like a jumbo version of the regular fish knife and fork) to serve fish especially if it is in a sauce?  Any advantage of this serviceware compared to athe conventional service spoona nd fork?

Comment: Hi Sanjit, welcome! You have a lot of questions here. The format that works best is to write one clear and definitively answerable question at a time. Question 1 is a well-constructed question. Question 2 is not very specific - what do you want to know about the fruit knife?

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to focus just on Question 1, and posting separate questions for your other questions.

Answer (score 1):

[Replacements.com](http://www.replacements.com/piecetype/flat_piece.htm) Will provide you with all the discriptions you are asking.  There are so many, it would be easier for you to go to the link yourself.

Comment: An answer should really be self-contained since links can go dead or change, but this link also doesn't answer the question. Here are the descriptions from your link for master butter and fish knives:

Fish knives are used in addition to the fish fork. Often, the fish knife and fish fork are used in addition to the typical 5-piece place setting. 

Master butter knives are meant to sit in the middle of the table or near the butter dish. This knife is meant for the cutting and serving of pats of butter. Generally, the master butter knife is passed around the table with the butter dish.

Answer (score -1):

1. A butter knife has a slight bend in the tip, other than that they're the same as far as i can tell.
2. A fruit knife has a real blade whilst a fish knife and butter knife are blunt. Think of it as a table paring knife.
3. Salad knife = plastic knife that will react less with veg than steel. I've never heard of a fruit fork, the only source I can find on Google is far from credible; apparently it's a long handled fork with fewer prongs. However considering how few results it turns up it seems more like something dreamt up by a marketing department to sell someone an extra set of forks.
4. You'd have to spoon the sauce separately. Fish slice + a deep knife (a fish knife is a broad knife but a standard chefs knife/Santoku or Chinese cleaver will get the job done) is the way I'd go.

Comment: A chef's knife is for preparing food. These knives are for serving and consumption. You wouldn't want to cut your fish fillet at the table with a chef's knife!

Comment: *Brain fart* True, though I wouldn't be worried about different types of table knives. I think you'd struggle to cook a fish fillet so that any knife couldn't manage it.